# how to integrate slack into website

Tags: c#, asp.net, slack-api

I'm trying to integrate slack into my website and I'm having some trouble. The point is so on the website someone can click "Log in with Slack" and be able to select a work space, login, and select a channel in that work space to install an app provided by the website.

I have the login part now using:

```
[Route("Account")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Route("Login")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
    {

        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
    }
}
```

and

```
options.Events = new OAuthEvents
{
    OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

        var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var userInfo = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        // var channelInfo = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        // Will read the hannel info and find the webhook url and stuff
        context.RunClaimActions(userInfo);
    }
};
```

but right now the JSON I'm reading only gets user info. How do I create something so it will prompt to ask for a channel selection also?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Have you checked out this part of the docu? https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a channel is not part of the standard process for installing a Slack app.

So I would suggest to add this on your website as part of the installation flow for the user. Since you will need a valid access token to get the list of channels it would be best to put this interaction after the Slack app is installed.

Then call the Slack API method [channels.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list) to get the list of all public channel and then present the user with the option to select one, e.g. with a drop-down box.